# When is a variable declaration in another class actually ran?

Tags: java

I've never really found out when exactly a variable declaration is actually ran in a program, when the variable resides in another class.

For instance:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

This program seems fairly simplistic to understand in terms of when the declaration is ran.

However consider this:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        System.out.println(test2.y);
    }
}
public class Test2 {
    public int y = 1;
}
```

and:

```java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Test2.y);
    }
}
public class Test2 {
    public static int y = 1;
}
```

When is the

```java
public int y = 1;
```

declaration ever ran in this program? It is only ever directly called, but isn't actually ran sequentially like the first example. Some clarification on how this actually works would be appreciated.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: This line `System.out.println(Test2.y);` in your second example will cause an error during compilation and you will never be able to run that code. That's because `Test2.y` is **not** `static`

Comment: I should have clarified that in the second example the variable y was static.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this `Test2 test2 = new Test2();` at that an object for with reference test2 was created in the memory, that object has one property as `y` with value assigned to it as `1`. So during the creation of object 'test2' , the line `public int y = 1;` was executed.

Comment: Thank you. And how about the static call?

Comment: Static variable are not instance variable they are class level variable. They are executed first after static block.

Comment: So when is the declaration ran?

Comment: If not static block then declaration ran first, otherwise after static block

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are exploring is of variable bindings(basically associating variable with it's data type & value).

Moreover I would highlight a couple of more things here.

*First:* `System.out.println(Test2.y);` is wrong as you can not print or access any non static variable in a static manner.

*Second:* in the below code :

`public Test() {
        Test2 test2 = new Test2();
        System.out.println(test2.y);
 }`

you can see we have aggregated Test2 class object in Test class's constructor, therefore any new object of class Test will have the Test2 instance & thus your code will successfully print 1 in this regard.`public int y = 1;` is a declaration & definition which has run at the compile time itself i.e. this variable's binding occurred at compile time. You can explore more towards compile time & run time binding for more knowledge on this concept.

Comment: And when taking into consideration that the variable y is static in the second example, what would be the explanation?

Comment: For static variables binding happen at compile time only & there's no concept of run time binding for them, therefore the declaration & initialisation of that variable 'y' has happened at the compile time. The same holds true for final variables as well even though you access them via instance/object. Both run time & compile time bindings can happen only in the case of non-final instance variables.